# connect to freesqldatabase using termux

Tags: python, mysql, linux, termux

I have created a free testing database on a web service.

How can I access it for terminal or from python. Which module should I use in python? Will MySQL connector work in this case?

In Linux terminal I tried

```
mysql -u sql12592118 -h sql12.freesqldatabase.com -p 3306
```

but I ended up with following error as I entered the password provided in mail

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'sql12592118'@'%' to database '3306'
> (env)

Comment: I am guessing you logging into the service to make sure the user name was exact, the rights section gave you the proper access, and the port number was correct?  If its a free service, it seems to me they would be milking the ports and not giving everyone the default port number of 3306?

Comment: 3306 is the default but if you are trying to pass it as an option it should `-P 3306` - capital not lowercase. The lowercase `-p` is the password option. For more details check [Command Options for Connecting to the Server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-options.html).